# What is the object for this expression?

Tags: grammaire, expressions

I am learning some french grammar online, I found this sentence `Je vois la fille danser.`. Can someone please break it down for me?

I mean what all things are used in making up this sentence and what are the noun/subject/object for this sentence?

The same question for this sentence as well `J'entends les enfants chanter la chanson.`

Merci d'avance!

Comment: Please ask only a question at a time and clarify which part of a sentence you cannot identify the role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both cases can  be lumped into a single one. This construction is typical of the so called verbs of perception :   *voir, regarder,, entendre, écouter, sentir, *, …
Following those verbs you find as object, besides nouns, clauses called "proposition subordonnée infinitive".

> ([Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-44913.php)) La subordonnée infinitive,
> principalement accompagne des verbes de perception.
>
> • J'entends papa crier.
> • Je vois les oiseaux voler.
>
> Ici, le verbe à l'infinitif peut changer de place
>
> dans la phrase sans en changer le sens.
> • J'entends crier papa.
> • Je vois voler les oiseaux.

> ([Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-35509.php))
>
> La proposition infinitive sert de complément d'objet aux verbes perceptifs comme « voir, entendre, écouter, sentir, regarder, etc. ».

"la fille danser" and "les enfants chanter la chanson" are the objects.

**Note** The inversion is not always  possible ; when the infinitive verb has an object it is not.

- <s>J'entends  chanter les enfants la chanson.</s>
- <s>J'entends  chanter  la chanson les enfants.</s>

Comment: Isn't the whole clause the object - *la fille danser*, *les enfants chanter la chanson*?